# python pandas shape data off CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, parsing

I have a data set in a `CSV` file which is downloaded from an accounting application into a `CSV` file. The way the data is structured is fine, except that it is split up in pages.  So, the CSV file has junk lines which aren't needed:

```
Company:ABC Ltd Date: 30-Mar-2017
GL Download

                                              Page No 1

GL Code,GL Name,Journal Id,Amount $,Vendor,Vendor Code,Text
1001200,SalesUK,5060400604,1,234.34,GroveT,234565,FC approved
```

more data comes down here....

```
Company:ABC Ltd Date: 30-Mar-2017
GL Download

                                              Page No 2

GL Code,GL Name,Journal Id,Amount $,Vendor,Vendor Code,Text
34560432,SalesUK,5060434567,4,356.19,Legend,135678,checked
```

Each time a page break is reached the header is repeated. I'm trying to upload data from the `CSV` file into a `pandas.DataFrame`, but the problem is in those page breaks and repetitive headers which I need to get rid of.

Is there a standard solution in pandas or maybe in python csv module to overcome lines of data, like those page numbers and headers?

Comment: If you know (or can calculate) the exact line numbers for the offensive data, you can tell `pandas.read.csv()` to ignore those rows.

Comment: @DYZ you mean `pd.read_csv(filepath)`? can you please clarify how can it help to get rid of junk lines? I thought that `skip_blank_rows` in read_csv constructor could help but it skips only blank rows. In my case some cells in junk rows are populated. And on top of that problem I've repeated headers on every page.

Comment: Yes, I mean `read_csv`, sorry for the typo. Look at the `skiprows` option. But I guess an even better solution is to set `error_bad_lines` to `False` and then remove the "dirty" rows from the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas allows you to pass your own parser.  If you pass the argument `engine='python'`, the expectation is that the `filepath_or_buffer` (the first argument) will be an iterator returning lists.  This is the same thing the `csv` module does.  Thus you can provide a generator that matches this signature like:

**Code:**

This code provides a custom parser for the report format in question.  It yields only the data lines.

```
def my_csv_reader(csvfile_handle):

    looking_for_header = True
    prev_line_blank = False
    for line in (x.strip() for x in csvfile_handle.readlines()):
        blank_line = len(line.strip()) == 0
        if looking_for_header:
            if not blank_line and prev_line_blank:
                looking_for_header = not line.startswith('GL Code,')
        elif not blank_line:
            yield line
        else:
            looking_for_header = True

        prev_line_blank = blank_line
```

**Code to use parser:**

To use the parser, we open the file, construct a csv_reader generator from that file, and then call `pandas.csv_reader()`:

```
with open('report.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(my_csv_reader(csvfile))
    df = pd.read_csv(
        reader, engine='python', header=None, index_col=False,
        names='GL Code,GL Name,Journal Id,Category,Amount $' \
              ',Vendor,Vendor Code,Text'.split(',')
    )
```

**Sample Results:**

```
    GL Code  GL Name  Journal Id  Category  Amount $  Vendor  Vendor Code  \
0   1001200  SalesUK  5060400604         1    234.34  GroveT       234565   
1  34560432  SalesUK  5060434567         4    356.19  Legend       135678   

          Text  
0      checked  
1  FC approved
```